# Is there any page level limitation in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

I"m tagging pages using virtual pageviews and i have about 5 levels. e.g:  **/Page level1/ Page level2/ Page level3/ Page level4/Page level5**.
when i drilldown the GA always concatenate **Page level4/Page level5**
so actual it looks like one page.
I"m using Standard Reporting.
Is there a limitation in the default page path levels?if no, do i need to change any settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you see it only group pages in 4 levels. Anything deeper than that will stay at level 4.

There's no way to remove that